# Reading a file signature and telling the difference between a zip file and a docx file

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have an upload routine where I read the first few bytes into an array and convert it to a hex string to get the file signature.

I have been reading the first 4 bytes into the array and everything seemed to be going fine until I ran across a problem with a .zip file and a .docx file.  They both have the same signature in the first 4 bytes: "50-4b-03-04".

So I looked at the next byte and for .docx it is "14" but it was on some .zip files as well.  I got looked up this file signature and found this sequence is for a lot of file types including JAR, ZIP, DOCX, XSLX, and Open Office documents.

Does anyone know of a good way to read the file signature and determine the file type accurately?  How does Windows know the difference? It has to be more than just the first 4 bytes.  I'm looking to read the file signatures for file uploads to ensure only approved file types are allowed to be uploaded.

Comment: Windows uses the file extension, the problem though is lots of files use the same headers for one reason or another. Why do you need to do this? https://filesignatures.net/index.php?page=search&search=504B0304&mode=SIG

Comment: A `docx` file is more or less a zip file: https://docs.fileformat.com/word-processing/docx/

Comment: I need to do this so if someone tries to upload a file that isn't supported by changing the extension, I can be sure that the file type is supported on upload.  So someone can take an .exe file and change the extension to .DOC if they want and upload it.  I need to make sure it isn't an .exe file.  I may need to check the file signature and compare the extension to determine if they  are office files.  If the extensions don't match, I can reject it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was put the file signatures into a database, put the signature length of file type and the extension.  If the file doesn't have an extension, it isn't uploaded.  If the file extension has changed from the signature, the routine will reject the file.  Here is the code in the routine that pulls the signatures and does a compare:

```
using var fileStream = file.OpenReadStream();
var signature = _context.FileSignatures.Select(f => new { f.FileSignature, f.AllowedFileType.FileExtension, f.SignatureLength })
                                       .Where(x => x.FileExtension == fileType);

byte[] bytes = new byte[signature.Max(x => x.SignatureLength)];
fileStream.Read(bytes, 0, signature.Max(x => x.SignatureLength));

string hexData = BitConverter.ToString(bytes);
var foundFile = await signature.FirstAsync(x => x.FileSignature == hexData);

return foundFile.FileExtension;
```

File signatures are stored in the table like this:

```
File Extension           FileSignature        SignatureLength
.PDF                     25-50-44-46          4
```

This way I can make sure the read the max number of bytes for the signature and get the extension.  If I want to include more files, I just add them to the database.